# Nodejs how to update client after external program has returned?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, architecture, external, executable

I'm writing a NodeJS application that mainly does 2 things:

- Run a web GUI (simple HTML/JS)
- Run external programs (binaries) based on user input

I want to be able to run those external programs asynchronously, as they can take several minutes to complete. And when they return, I want to update the web GUI to display the results. Here is the very basic concept:

[image]

1. User enters parameters and press the action button.
2. Server runs the external program with params from user.
3. When the program returns, Server takes the output (an XML file) and put
   the content in DB.
4. Server then updates the client with results from the DB.

It should be noted that the user can run several external programs at the same time, with different parameters.

**How should I update the client** (web GUI) when the external program has finished: does it have to be the client polling for updates (e.g. by looking in the DB if the result is here) ? Or is there a way to "push" from server to client ?

I'm also looking at design examples to accomplish this, so please feel free to provide advices and resources regarding this architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm starting to work with queues in my app and I was having the same question as you.

One solution that I thought (but still didn't try) would be to start a socket (using socket.io) when the user start these kind of async process and also send a callback url (that points to your express server) to the process.
The callback would have a client/session id parameter to identify who made the request and choose the correct socket to push the message back. 
Using socket, you wouldn't have to do pooling from your client to your server.

I think this is called Pub/Sub. There are some technologies like [Redis](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) that could also help implementing it.

I also would like to received feedback on this approach. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

You definitely want to use Socket.io, as Tulio suggested. You requested ideas of how to update the client, specifically, so i'm going to assume you have an idea of how you're going to know when you're server is done executing the external programs.

A websocket allows your server to send data back to the client at any time, such as when your program finishes. It eliminates the need for you to use long polling or ajax techniques, which may take up more of your development cycle then you might desire.

Socket.io is **one of the best, and most popular** websocket wrappers out there. It's cross-browser, and even mobile support is unparalleled. Basically, if you're running a node.js server, you want to use socket.io.

This is a great tutorial I recommended to one of my colleagues last night:

https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-socketio

And, to save you many hours of searching, I figured I would also mention that to create cross-file client-side sockets. You simply have to declare the socket variable in your main html files:

index.html:

```
<html>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket;
    var connected=false;
</script>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
socket = io.connect('http//localhost'); //Make sure you include http//

socket.on('connect'){

    connected = true;
});
```

secondary.js:

```
setInterval(function(){

     if(connected === true){

          socket.emit('doesThisWork', true);
     };

}, 100);
```

Also, to force a new connection you do:

```
socket = io.connect('http//localhost', {'force new connection': true);
```

To make a socket secure, you want to secure your url... e.g. HTTPS keeps your socket secure too.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it seems there are two types of updates you need.

1) When the external program finishes execution

...you need to tell the express server what has happened and the result. The easiest method here is to simply hit a method on express's public (or private) API it already has.

For example, using the [request library](https://github.com/request/request):

```
var request = require('request');

var EXPRESS_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/task'

//...

// This is called after you save results to database
function onTaskCompleted(taskId, result) {
    request.put(
        {
            url: EXPRESS_URL + '/' + taskId,
            json: result
        },
        function (err, httpResponse, body) {
            // Handle response
        }
    );
}
```

You would also need a corresponding `/api/task/:id/` route in your express server and some security, if these servers are not on the same machine.

2) When express server finds out a task has finished

... you need to notify currently active users. In this scenario, this would happen inside the `/api/task/:id/` request handler. The best way to notify user's browser from here is through [socket.io](http://socket.io/). It's really easy to install in node and will take care of all legacy browser concerns.

On the server, you would use it like this:

```
app.put('/api/task/:id', function (req, res) {
    var payload = {
        id: req.params.id,
        result: req.data
    };
    io.emit('task_completed', payload);
});
```

On the client:

```
io.on('task_completed', function (data) {
    alert('Task ' + data.id + ' has finished with result ' + data.result);
});
```